# Security Implications of Running Solaris Kerberos TGT Expiration Warning Deamon

Tags: security, solaris, kerberos

Section 2.3.6 of the [CIS Solaris Benchmark](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/solaris/CIS_Solaris_10_Benchmark_v5.0.0.pdf) states the following:

> **Description**: While Kerberos can be a security enhancement, if the local site is not currently using Kerberos then there is no need to have the Kerberos TGT expiration warning enabled.
>
> **Rationale**: Unless your organization specifically requires uses Kerberos, disable it.
>
> **Remediation**: To disable the Kerberos TGT expiration warning, run the following command:
> svcadm disable svc:/network/security/ktkt_warn

Are there any security implications of actually having the Kerberos TGT expiration warning deamon running?

Answer (score 0):

No. If your organization doesn't use Kerberos then it's unnecessary, and shouldn't be installed on a users computer, because it would take resources (cpu, ram memory..).